# Parse query with no current user

Tags: android, parse-platform

I have a working app on android and IOS.

The first activity on both is a log in screen.
The second activity is a search function that allows you to find nearby users using parse.

However I am trying the make the app allow users to search without having to login.

This was easy to do with IOS.

In android I have changed my startup activity to activity 2 (the search activity) in the manifest file and it loads fine but obviously there is no current user.

When I try to run the query now, the app just stalls and in the debugger it says the user is null. I am guessing this is the problem here.

So I then tried to create an anonous user in the oncreate method using the lines..

```
  ParseAnonymousUtils.logIn(new LogInCallback() {
        @Override
        public void done(ParseUser user, ParseException e) {
            if (e != null) {
                Log.d("MyApp", "Anonymous login failed.");
            } else {
                Log.d("MyApp", "Anonymous user logged in.");
            }
        }
    });
```

This then fails with the message

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.io.File com.parse.ParsePlugins.getParseDir()' on a null object reference at com.parse.Parse.getParseDir(Parse.java:499)

Oddly enough though. This bit of code does work if i put it in activity 1, but the app then gets stuck when it tries to launch activity 2.

Does anyone know what is happening? Or how I can solve my original original problem?

Thanks

Comment: Do you do your Parse.initialize() in your Activity 1?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error appears when Parse is not initialized. I'm guessing you put your `Parse.initialize()` code in your activity. When you go to another one, the initialization is lost. You need to extend your Application class so that it holds a single initialization for the whole app.

```
public class Application extends android.app.Application {

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        Parse.initialize(new Parse.Configuration.Builder(this)
                .applicationId("id")
                .clientKey("key")
                .server("server")
                .enableLocalDataStore()
                .build()
        );
        ParseUser.enableAutomaticUser();
   }
}
```

And this in your AndroidManifest.xml

```
<application
        android:name=".Application"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/logo"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
```

Comment: Thank you Dmitri. My Parse.initialize() was still in activity one and all fixed as you suggested.